# apt-rollback messed things up, now I'm unable to run apt upgrade

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dependencies

I get conflict on libsystemd which I didn't manage to fix,
Help please!

```
sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apport-gtk : Depends: apport (>= 0.41) but it is not installed
 libnss-systemd : Depends: systemd (= 249.11-0ubuntu3.6)
 libsystemd0 : Breaks: libsystemd0:i386 (!= 249.11-0ubuntu3.4) but 249.11-0ubuntu3.6 is installed
 libsystemd0:i386 : Breaks: libsystemd0 (!= 249.11-0ubuntu3.6) but 249.11-0ubuntu3.4 is installed
 libudev-dev : Depends: libudev1 (= 249.11-0ubuntu3.6) but 249.11-0ubuntu3.4 is installed
 libudev1 : Breaks: libudev1:i386 (!= 249.11-0ubuntu3.4) but 249.11-0ubuntu3.6 is installed
 libudev1:i386 : Breaks: libudev1 (!= 249.11-0ubuntu3.6) but 249.11-0ubuntu3.4 is installed
 python3 : PreDepends: python3-minimal (= 3.10.6-1~22.04) but 3.10.4-0ubuntu2 is installed
           Depends: python3.10 (>= 3.10.6-1~) but 3.10.4-3ubuntu0.1 is installed
           Depends: libpython3-stdlib (= 3.10.6-1~22.04) but 3.10.4-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-dev : Depends: python3 (= 3.10.4-0ubuntu2) but 3.10.6-1~22.04 is installed
 systemd-timesyncd : Depends: systemd (= 249.11-0ubuntu3.6)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

EDIT:

Tried `apt --fix-broken install` and apt clean, no luck..

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apport-gtk : Depends: apport (>= 0.41) but it is not installed
 libnss-systemd : Depends: systemd (= 249.11-0ubuntu3.6)
 libsystemd0 : Breaks: libsystemd0:i386 (!= 249.11-0ubuntu3.4) but 249.11-0ubuntu3.6 is installed
 libsystemd0:i386 : Breaks: libsystemd0 (!= 249.11-0ubuntu3.6) but 249.11-0ubuntu3.4 is installed
 libudev-dev : Depends: libudev1 (= 249.11-0ubuntu3.6) but 249.11-0ubuntu3.4 is installed
 libudev1 : Breaks: libudev1:i386 (!= 249.11-0ubuntu3.4) but 249.11-0ubuntu3.6 is installed
 libudev1:i386 : Breaks: libudev1 (!= 249.11-0ubuntu3.6) but 249.11-0ubuntu3.4 is installed
 python3 : PreDepends: python3-minimal (= 3.10.6-1~22.04) but 3.10.4-0ubuntu2 is installed
           Depends: python3.10 (>= 3.10.6-1~) but 3.10.4-3ubuntu0.1 is installed
           Depends: libpython3-stdlib (= 3.10.6-1~22.04) but 3.10.4-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-dev : Depends: python3 (= 3.10.4-0ubuntu2) but 3.10.6-1~22.04 is installed
 systemd-timesyncd : Depends: systemd (= 249.11-0ubuntu3.6)
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Comment: Have you tried the commend that is suggested?  `sudo apt --fix-broken install`  If so, please include the output of that command.

Comment: What is `apt-rollback`?

Comment: As the name hints - it rolls back last action (or n actions) done by apt

Comment: added fix-broken output to original post

Comment: What did you try to rollback?

Comment: I upgraded and some things stopped working so I wanted to roolback to previous versions

Comment: It looks like you may have messed up python. Did you maybe try to change or modify the python version?

Comment: Hi David, no...

Answer (score 0):

You could try to remove the listed packages from a recovery terminal. If that succeeds, you will be removing many, many packages. After that, you can restore the core desktop with a single command:

```
sudo apt-install ubuntu-desktop-minimal
```

(or `ubuntu-desktop`, which also includes several user applications).

You should then be able to log in to your desktop. Your custom (GUI-) applications will need to be reinstalled, but will look and behave as before, because user data and configuration (user and system) have been preserved.

See [here](https://linuxhint.com/boot-ubuntu-into-recovery-mode/) for instructions on how to log in to a recovery terminal.

If that does not work, try Option 2 [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1432192/558158). This involves reinstalling the entire system with the live installer, however in a special way that preserves user data and configuration.

Comment: Can I remove udev and systemd?

Comment: Your alternative is a reinstall, Option 2

Comment: Method 2 - Choose " Something else" in the installer doesn't seems to work, I can't proceed installation