# Can't find terminal and other apps in ubuntu

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, ubuntu-gnome

I have ubuntu 22 and it was working properly. today I opened it and found that the terminal was not found and also the dock of ubuntu was not in its proper position. I found it down and its shape is different.
I need some help, please. I don't have any time to reinstall ubuntu again and I have a lot of programs and configurations on the currently broken ubuntu :(

Comment: What is the last change you made to your system before it stopped working?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I was trying to fix an issue with a pyGuion of python. I tried alot of methods online but i dont know which one cause this

Comment: @OrganicMarble even the internet is not working. It's connected to wifi but not to the internet

Comment: No way to be sure, but it sounds like you broke python on your system, and might need to reinstall.

Comment: Ubuntu 22 is Ubuntu Core 22 the only version of Ubuntu using just one number. Is this what you are running? If not pleas EDIT the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have messed up with python, which accordingly [breaks your system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384033/removed-python-3-and-now-ubuntu-software-center-terminal-and-other-applications).

> I don't have any time to reinstall ubuntu again

I am sorry, but wrongly administering the system is your act, and you have to take the consequences. Surely take the time to backup all your critical user data if your backup is not yet up-to-date before any attempt to repair the system.

1 – You may, if your packaging system is not broken, be able to restore your system by reinstalling the essential components of the Ubuntu desktop. Get to a terminal and reinstall `ubuntu-desktop` with the command

`sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

If you can make it to the login screen, get to a terminal by hitting Ctrl+Alt+F4 and log in on the TTY. After the reinstallation, log out of the TTY then return to the login screen (Alt+F1) and log in to the graphical interface.

Alternatively, boot to a recovery prompt with network access using the Grub menu.

If that does not work then

2 – There is a way to reinstall a system keeping current data and configuration: one can install without formatting the partitions (Choose " Something else"  in the installer). There is a big chance that that will repair the system.

3 – A fresh reinstall will be your only rescue of none of the previous attempts succeeded. The advantage here is that little technical knowledge is required.

Comment: Yes, this solved the issue. I also reinstalled the gnome using `sudo apt install gnome` and everything is fine now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have no apps open and right click on your empty desktop. Click the option called "Settings" and that will open the Settings app. In settings, go to "Appearance" and make sure that the dock is enabled, meaning that "Auto-hide the dock" is **Not** enabled. If that doesn't work, then close Settings and go back to your blank desktop, right click, and choose "Open in terminal". This will open an empty terminal, and you can then type the name of any application you have, like "firefox". Make sure you don't have any capital letters in that command.

Comment: No "open in terminal" . I can't find any terminal here :((

Comment: @Omar_Hafez is the "Settings" option there?

Comment: Yes, but didn't find auto-hide the dock also.

Comment: no. ithing the gnome is broken or the something broken in the ubuntu

Comment: @Omar_Hafez try Ctrl+Alt+T from your desktop, which should open the terminal

Comment: I tried eveything possible to open the terminal but didnt

Comment: @Omar_Hafez Ctrl+Alt+Backspace will restart Gnome, without restarting the system, which might fix your problem

Comment: the same issue :(

Comment: Any idea how gnome could have been changed?